# Combine two objects while keeping object name

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm not totally sure if I'm using the correct terminology or not, I'm relatively new to node.

I have two JSON objects

```js
const objA = {
  key1: value1
  ...
}

const objB = {
  key2: value2
 ...
}
```

that I want to combine into one while keeping the two object names, so it would look a bit like:

```js
const newObj = {objA: { key1: value1,...}, objB: { key2: value2,...}}
```

So far in my research I've found `Object.assign(objA,objB)` which just combines them as `newObj = {key1: value1, key2: value2, ...}`

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const newObj = {objA, objB};
```

You can assign them into new object like above.

Comment: Wow, I am an idiot. Can't tell you how long I've been trying to get this to work and completely missed the most obvious solution... Thanks!

Comment: @AndyReifman - Keep in mind that this creates a new object that references the original `objA` and `objB` so if you change the originals, those changes will be reflected in `newObj` also.  That may or may not be what you want, but it's important to know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting it out there as a reference if you wanted to combine the `key` and `values` from both objects into one you could always use [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) if you decide to not go with a multi-level object:

```js
const objA = {
  key1: "value1"
}

const objB = {
  key2: "value2"
}

const objCombined = {...objA, ...objB }

console.log(objCombined)
```

Comment: It seems from the question that this is precisely what the OP doesn't want.

Comment: This doesn't keep the original object variable

Comment: Which was why I mentioned "putting it out there" in case he changes his approach or if this was referenced from a search query in the future.